# Why my merge sort is not working?

Tags: java, mergesort

I tried to use merge sort. however, it keeps popping me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Can anyone let me know why?

I totally confused. Did i miss something?

```
public class InversionSearch {
    public int[] mergeSort(int[] array){
        if (array.length == 1) {
            return array;
        }
        int[] first = new int[array.length/2];
        int[] second = new int[array.length - first.length];

        System.arraycopy(array, 0, first, 0, first.length);
        System.arraycopy(array, first.length, second, 0, second.length);

        int[] result = merge(mergeSort(first), mergeSort(second));
        return result;
    }

    public int[] merge(int[] first, int[] second) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int[] temp = new int[first.length + second.length];
        for (int k = 0; k < temp.length; k++) {
            if (first[i] < second[j]) {
                temp[k] = first[i];
                i++;
            }else {
                temp[k] = second[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input = {1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6};
        InversionSearch iSearch = new InversionSearch();
        iSearch.mergeSort(input);
    }

}
```

Comment: What line? Sharing the full error makes it easier for people to help you without having to trace through all the code

Answer (score 1):

your `for` loop is wrong

```
for (int k = 0; k < temp.length; k++) {
    if (first[i] < second[j]) {
        temp[k] = first[i];
        i++;
    }else {
        temp[k] = second[j];
        j++;
    }
 }
```

You are not checking whether `i` and `j` are the correct index or not.

For something like

```
first = { 1, 2, 3, 4 } second = { 5, 6, 7 }
```

your for loop will go for k times and k is 7, after 5 iterations `i`  value will be 5 and you will get `ArrayIndexOutofBoundException`.

proper way to write this is :

```
int k=0;
while(i < first.length && j< second.length){
    if (first[i] < second[j]) {
        temp[k] = first[i];
        i++;
    }else {
        temp[k] = second[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}

//for corner cases where some elements are left out
while(i < first.length) {
    temp[k] = first[i];
    k++;
    i++;
}
while(j < second.length) {
    temp[k] = second[j];
    k++;
    j++;
}
```